# <readystate> doesn't work: Table cells in a HTML.Document don't seem to fully update after clicking an object (thus changing table; URL stays same)

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

All that I know now about VBA is mostly thanks to this site - you are the best <3

However, for last two days I've been looking for a solution and couldn't work it out by usual research.

- Background:

I have a site with a table in it. Table represents prices for product X. There are many products, but table shows only active product. When I click on Y/Z/M, the URL stays same, only table itself updates. I need to build a database for many products, so I loop through the list by looking for  elements and clicking on them and then try to fish rows/cells/etc.

- Problem:

For same code, same list, same data I end up with non identical databases. Some entries are missing, some entries repeat prices of previous products etc.

- Theory what's not working:

After thorough F8-testing, I think this is not working properly:

```
    Do Until Not appIE.Busy And appIE.READYSTATE = 4
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
```

When I go through my macro by F8, all data is being fished properly. It looks like somehow the VBA doesn't wait for the html.document to fully update.

- What I'de done so far:

I played around with various configurations (Do While, Do Until Not etc) of the usual loop.

I added the site to "trusted" sites in IE, as someone somewhere suggested it would help. Got scary errors afterwords and I had no idea what to do with them, so "untrusted" the site. No more error messages.

I tried to "reset" the HTML.Document.

I figured out where in the page the actual info about status bar on screen shows up and asked VBA to make sure that  name changes from "Modal In" to "Modal":

```
    Set checkA = html.getElementById("processingModal")
    Dim trytry As String
    Do While trytry = "modal in"
             trytry = checkA.className
             Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Loop
```

I still end up with messed up output.

Below, I'm adding my full code. I would also appreciate greatly any advice, as this is my first web scraping code ever and I'm self taught.

Many thanks in advance, Good People!

```
Sub try_this()
'trying scraping from web

Dim appIE As Object
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim lngRow, i, lngColumn, lngYear, a, s As Long
Dim tblSummary As IHTMLTable
Dim tblRows As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim tblRow As IHTMLElement
Dim tblCells As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim tblCell As IHTMLElement
Dim tblDataValue As String
Dim VintagesList As IHTMLElement
Dim Vintages As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Vintage As IHTMLElement
Dim VintageYear As String
Dim BtlSizesList As IHTMLElement
Dim BtlSizes As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim BtlSize As IHTMLElement
Dim BtlSizeValue As String
Dim btlSizeID As String
Dim objA As IHTMLElement, checkA As IHTMLElement
Dim strAddress As String, strVintageY As String
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double


StartTime = Timer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'part 1: open IE browser and go to page with products
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .Navigate "My web Page"
    .Visible = True
End With
    Do While appIE.Busy     'so far works all right
        DoEvents
    Loop

Set html = appIE.Document

For lngYear = 2 To 16   'product category list

    Application.StatusBar = "Downloading data for year " & lngYear - 1 & " of 15..."

    strVintageY = Sheets("Dict").Range("A" & lngYear).Value 'first cathegory
    strAddress = Sheets("Dict").Range("D2").Value & strVintageY & Sheets("Dict").Range("D4").Value & strVintageY  'changes physical address in a browser

    appIE.Navigate strAddress
    appIE.Visible = True

    Do While appIE.Busy
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))      ' aaand wait some more, because the trick doesn't work and I'm desperate
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    Set html = AppIE.Document  'this is the EDIT part

   'STEP 2: get available product names
   Set BtlSizesList = html.getElementById("auction-size-tabs")
   Set BtlSizes = BtlSizesList.Children

    i = 2                                              'i=2, we'll start to print data into row 2
    Sheets("Dict").Range("B2:B100").Clear
    
    For Each BtlSize In BtlSizes
             BtlSizeValue = BtlSize.innerText

             Sheets("Dict").Cells(i, 2).Value = BtlSizeValue
             i = i + 1
    Next
   
  'Step 2b: Fish Prices Data Table
  lngRow = Sheets("Database").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
  s = Sheets("Dict").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  's = last row with product's name

  For a = 2 To s
                
    btlSizeID = Sheets("Dict").Range("B" & a).Value
    Set objA = html.getElementById(btlSizeID).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)   'click right product on the web page
      objA.Click
    
    'Readystate and waiting:
    Do Until Not appIE.Busy And appIE.READYSTATE = 4                                   'wait for page to load
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    
     'this is part where I physically check if the load bar is still there:
    Set checkA = html.getElementById("processingModal")
    Dim trytry As String
   
    Do While trytry = "modal in"
             trytry = checkA.className
             Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Loop
    
  'I even tried to "reset" html.document. To be honest no idea what I'm doing here.
    Set html = Nothing
    Set html = appIE.Document
     
    Set tblSummary = html.getElementById("summaryTable")            'find the table
    Set tblRows = tblSummary.Rows                                   'get list of rows in the table
    
        For Each tblRow In tblRows
             Set tblCells = tblRow.Cells
             
             If lngRow >= 2 Then
             Sheets("Database").Range("B" & lngRow).Value = btlSizeID  'condition will be removed once I figure how to skip 1st row of table in HTML
             End If
             
             lngColumn = 3
             For Each tblCell In tblCells                        
                      tblDataValue = tblCell.innerText
                      
                      lngColumn = lngColumn + 1
             Next
             
            If lngRow >= 2 Then
            Sheets("Database").Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = strVintageY                    'paste product's category into column A
            End If
            
            lngRow = lngRow + 1  'i will be row# that will have new info pasted in it
                 
        Next    
Next a 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Next lngYear

Set html = Nothing
Set appIE = Nothing

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = False


MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation


End Sub
```

**Update:** As suggested, I added missing line that re-sets HTML.Documnet after .Navigate event. This didn't fix my problem though.

Comment: Every time you trigger a navigation event, a new document object is created, so you need to get a new reference to that document before proceeding.  Other than that, it's very difficult to debug what might be the issue with your code without a URL or any relevant page source HTML

Comment: Thank  you @TimWilliams!  
So I need to get new HTML document after this?:  
     appIE.Navigate strAddress  
     appIE.Visible = True  

Page that I'm trying to scrap is this:  
https://www.vinfolio.com/do/wineprices/detail/2002_mouton-rothschild?vintageService.wine.id=55025&vintageService.year=2002  

I change years according to a list. Table is "Auction History Data".

Comment: Yes, whenever you call Navigate or whenever you click something on the page which triggers a reload/update

Comment: @TimWilliams - just corrected this mistake, but there is no improvement in quality of data scrapped. Sometimes I get just 1st row of table with no values, sometimes I get same/partially same table as the one for previous product, like the cells values within HTML.Document are not properly updated.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to your current version?

Comment: Added. Line 20-ish of the code. I changed nothing else. Tried to add more seconds to wait time, but that doesn't help.